# Netty 4.1: Send multiple WebSocketFrame Fragments and Closer with ContinuationWebSocketFrame

Tags: java, websocket, netty

I have a [Subscriber](https://www.reactive-streams.org/reactive-streams-1.0.0-javadoc/org/reactivestreams/Subscriber.html) that receives [sequential callbacks](https://www.reactive-streams.org/reactive-streams-1.0.0-javadoc/org/reactivestreams/Subscriber.html#onNext-T-) on the next available payload and a [subsequent callback](https://www.reactive-streams.org/reactive-streams-1.0.0-javadoc/org/reactivestreams/Subscriber.html#onComplete--) when the last payload has been received. (Simplified code below)

What I want to do is send WebSocketFrame fragments on each payload callback and close the whole logical frame when the subscriber completes.

I have tried:

1. Start with a `new TextWebSocketFrame(false, 0, buf)` and close with a `new TextWebSocketFrame(true, 0, buf)`.
2. Start with a `new ContinuationWebSocketFrame(false, 0, buf)`, continue with `new TextWebSocketFrame(false, 0, buf)`and close with a `new TextWebSocketFrame(true, 0, buf)`.
3. Start with a `new ContinuationWebSocketFrame(false, 0, buf)`, continue with `new TextWebSocketFrame(false, 0, buf)`and close with a `new ContinuationWebSocketFrame(true, 0, buf)`.

.... and a few more combinations, but my Chrome Browser client (Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)) either reports an outright WebSock protocol violation or complains that multiple ContinuationWebSocketFrames have been received.

Can you point me in the right direction to get this working correctly with the right sequence of the correctly configured WebSocketFrames ?

Many thanks.

```
static class DataReceiver implements Subscriber<Object> {
    private Channel channel;
    private final AtomicBoolean firstFrame = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public DataReceiver(Channel channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
        s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);          
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Object obj) {
        ByteBuf buf = JSONOps.serialize(obj, channel.alloc().ioBuffer()); 
        if (firstFrame.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            channel.writeAndFlush(new ContinuationWebSocketFrame(false, 0, buf));
        } else {
            channel.writeAndFlush(new TextWebSocketFrame(false, 0, buf));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        log.error("Subscriber Error", t);
        // TODO: Handle error
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
//          channel.writeAndFlush(new ContinuationWebSocketFrame(true, 0, Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER));
        channel.writeAndFlush(new TextWebSocketFrame(true, 0, Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER));

    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's now working. There were 2 issues. One was that I did not have a [WebSocketFrameAggregator](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/websocketx/WebSocketFrameAggregator.html) in my pipeline. Secondly, the closing [ContinuationWebSocketFrame](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/websocketx/ContinuationWebSocketFrame.html) must have some content. It did not work when I closed the aggregation with [Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/buffer/Unpooled.html#EMPTY_BUFFER).

As it turned out, I needed to insert a JSON array closer at the end anyways.

The working (simplified class) looked like this:

```
static class DataReceiver implements Subscriber<Object> {
    private Channel channel;
    private final AtomicBoolean firstFrame = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public DataReceiver(Channel channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
        s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);          
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Object obj) {
        ByteBuf buf = JSONOps.serialize(obj, channel.alloc().ioBuffer(4196));
        if (firstFrame.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            ByteBuf b = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer("[".getBytes()), buf);
            channel.writeAndFlush(new TextWebSocketFrame(false, 0, b));
        } else {
            ByteBuf b = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(",".getBytes()), buf);
            channel.writeAndFlush(new ContinuationWebSocketFrame(false, 0, b));
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        log.error("Subscriber Error", t);
        // TODO: Handle error
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        channel.writeAndFlush(new ContinuationWebSocketFrame(true, 0, Unpooled.wrappedBuffer("]".getBytes())));
    }       
}
```